# How to set default checked radio button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to set the default checked radio button while using `ng-repeat`. The below code is what I'm working with:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" id="dbHandle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label ng-repeat="handle in handles" for="" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="dbHandle" value="{{handle.handle}}" autocomplete="off">
    {{handle.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like for the first `handle` to be checked on page load. I've tried using the following ternary on the `input` element, but to no effect:

```
ng-checked="$index === 0 ? true : false"
```

Comment: Try `ng-checked='$first'` on radio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-model` on your inputs:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" id="dbHandle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label ng-repeat="handle in handles" for="" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="dbHandle" value="{{handle.handle}}" ng-model="selectedOption" autocomplete="off">
    {{handle.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Then, set the bound value to the handle of your choice:

```
$scope.selectedOption = handles[0].handle;
// Or:
$scope.selectedOption = 2;
```

Angular will automatically check the correct element:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.handles = [
      { handle: 0, name: 'Zero' },
      { handle: 1, name: 'One' },
      { handle: 2, name: 'Two' },
      { handle: 3, name: 'Three' }
    ];
    
    $scope.selectedOption = $scope.handles[2].handle;
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="myController">
    <label ng-repeat="handle in handles" for="" class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="dbHandle" value="{{handle.handle}}" ng-model="selectedOption" autocomplete="off">{{handle.name}}
    </label>
  </form>
</body>
```